# Reading and Writing to Sockets, Java

Tags: java, sockets

I have a little problem with reading and writing to Sockets in my Server/Client Java application. Server have connection to database. I want to send an object "Employee" consist User Data (Name, Surname, Password) to Server, then Server look up to database about this user and resend to Client information - positive (1) or negative (-1).

First, when I want to send an object Employee, I've got :
"java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error" 
I have my Firewall turned off.

Second, when I want to send and receive just int through writeInt - readInt method for test, I can't to read anything on Server.

What's the problem? Please help.

Code Server:

```
class ClientCommunication implements Runnable {
    private Socket incoming;

    public ClientCommunication(Socket clientSocket) {
        incoming = clientSocket;

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {                   
                    serverObjectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(
                            incoming.getOutputStream());
                    serverObjectInput = new ObjectInputStream(
                            incoming.getInputStream()); 
                } finally {
                    incoming.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        synchronized(this) {
            while (true) {
                try{                        
                    int operation = serverObjectInput.readInt();                        

                    switch(operation) {
                    case 1:
                            Employee employee = (Employee) serverObjectInput.readObject();
                            String SelectUserDataSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM pracownik where Imie = ? AND Nazwisko = ? AND Haslo = ?";
                            PreparedStatement CheckEmployeeLogin;
                            CheckEmployeeLogin = conn.prepareStatement(SelectUserDataSQL);

                            CheckEmployeeLogin.setString(1, employee.getFirstName());
                            CheckEmployeeLogin.setString(2, employee.getLastName());
                            CheckEmployeeLogin.setString(3, new String(employee.getPassword()));                    

                            ResultSet resultSQL = CheckEmployeeLogin.executeQuery();
                            if (resultSQL.next()) 
                                if (resultSQL.getInt("COUNT") == 0)
                                    serverObjectOutput.writeInt(1);
                                else serverObjectOutput.writeInt(-1);
                            break;
                }
            } catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)                 
            {                   
            }
          }
        }
    }
}

class ServerStart implements Runnable {
    private int portNumber;

    public ServerStart(int portNumber) {
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
    }

    public void run() {


        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            stat = conn.createStatement();

        } catch (SQLException e1) {             
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {              
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {              
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);                

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }


        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket incoming = serverSocket.accept();

                clientSockets.add(incoming);

                Runnable r = new ClientCommunication(incoming);
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }
    }       
}
```

Code Client:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (isConnected == false) {
                    String ServerIP = ip.getText().trim();

                    int ServerPort = Integer
                            .parseInt(port.getText().trim());


                    try {
                        ClientSocket = new Socket(ServerIP, ServerPort);                        

                        clientObjectInput = new ObjectInputStream(
                                ClientSocket.getInputStream());
                        clientObjectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(
                                ClientSocket.getOutputStream());

                        isConnected = true;
                    } catch (IOException ex) {                          
                    }
                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {                               
                            ClientLoginFrame login = new ClientLoginFrame();

                            Employee employee = login.getEmployee();                                                                

                            clientObjectOutput.writeObject(employee);                               
                            int result = clientObjectInput.readInt();

                            if(result == 1)
                            {       
                                  // DO SOMETHING
                            }
                            else { 
                                ClientSocket.close();                                   
                            }                           
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, you are asking two questions here: getting a SocketException when using an Object for client-server-communication and "cannot reading nothing" when using readInt. Can you somehow melt down the code example until only the problematic gode is left, and also write exactly what error you getr when using "readInt"/"writeInt"?

Comment: I don't have any error when I using writeInt() and readInt(), but If I want for a test, writeInt(1) on Client, and make readInt() on Server, then show received value, like console.append("" + result), I've got nothing on console.

Comment: I revised a code a little bit, It's shorter and easy to read I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add an ex.printStackTrace() to see what is happening in your

   `catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)`
2. Server side, on your `ClientCommunication` class: it seems you are closing the socket before entering the `while` loop. So the socket is already closed and cannot send/receive messages. You should NOT call `incoming.close()` there, but at the end of your `run()` method.